# Python JIRA Package cant authenticate against Jira server

Tags: python, authentication, jira

I am trying to use the Python JIRA Package to connect to our Jira installation.

This is my code:

```
from cred import *
import requests
from jira import JIRA


jira = JIRA(server='https://theinstallatationofjira.com/jira', basic_auth=('myemail@company.com', 'MyTokenString'))

print(jira.projects())
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
<!-- HTTPError401 -->
    <div class="aui-page-panel" ><div class="aui-page-panel-inner">
            <main role="main" id="main" class="aui-page-panel-content" >
                    <div class="aui-page-header" ><div class="aui-page-header-inner">
                            <div class="aui-page-header-main" >
                                    <h1>Unauthorized (401)</h1>
                                </div>
                        </div></div>
                    <div class="aui-message aui-message-warning warning">
                            <p>Encountered a <code>&quot;401 - Unauthorized&quot;</code> error while loading this page.</p>
                            <p>Basic Authentication Failure - Reason : AUTHENTICATED_FAILED</p>
                            <p><a href="/jira/secure/MyJiraHome.jspa">Go to Jira home</a></p>
                        </div>
                </main>
        </div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Authentification on the web gui works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
jira_options = {'server': options.jira_server,
                        'verify': 'cert.pem'}
        if options.jira_password:
            jira_password = options.jira_password
        else:
            jira_password = getpass.getpass()

        jira = JIRA(options=jira_options,
                    # Note the tuple
                    basic_auth=(options.jira_user, 
                                jira_password))
        # Test the connection by retrieving server information
        info = jira.server_info()
```

Comment: The first parameter needs to be a dict with a server key value